# How do I decide whether to use Pow-Pow or Fishbones?

Tags: league-of-legends

Jinx's Q switch between her minigun and rocket launcher. While the minigun (Pow-Pow) adds attack speed, the rocket launcher (Fishbones) does 110% damage and AoE. When do I use what? The 110% damage is cool but so is the attack speed.

Comment: Remember that each rocket fired by Fishbones consumes 20 mana.

Comment: If the target is within range of your minigun, use Pow-Pow.  If the target is outside minigun range, switch to Fishbones for long range harass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mini-gun has a better rate of fire, while the rocket launcher has extra range and damage, causes full splash damage with roughly melee attack range around the target, and also costs mana per shot.

**Laning phase**

Most of the time, you should be using the mini-gun. The very high rate of fire at all levels means great sustain with Doran's Blade should you need it, and gives you more flexibility and error tolerance when last hitting minions, especially in early levels. Against champions, use it when you commit to a fight like a regular ADC would use autoattacks.

The rocket launcher is excellent for harassing the enemy laners, as it has bonus range and damage, and might even hit both enemy laners for double damage in total. Because of the splash damage, you can effectively increase the total range even further by attacking a minion in front of and close to an enemy champion.

The rocket launcher also helps last hitting if you have multiple enemy minions close to death so you don't lose any, or pushing the lane hard when the time is right. Be careful not to use it all the time though, as it will drain your mana. Note that the rate of fire buff from the mini-gun will apply to the first rocket fired, which helps greatly with both AoE last hitting and harassing.

**Team fights**

In team fights, the mini-gun has better single-target sustained damage than the rocket launcher, just because of the attack speed buff. The rocket launcher might be useful for continuous use only when the enemy team is clumped up, such as when J4 or Orianna gets off a really good ult, catching the whole enemy team. Usually though, the mini-gun is better.

Exception: If your target is close to death and you want to make absolutely sure that your next autoattack is really the last, you can switch from mini-gun to rocket launcher for one rocket at both full attack speed and the extra 10% AD damage. After the first rocket, the attack speed buff is lost, however, so your damage output will then drop dramatically.

Comment: Do you happen to know how Fishbones' bonus damage interacts with crits and IE?

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Wiki says the 10% bonus can crit, haven't tested it myself. If it does, IE would affect it as well, as it applies to all critical damage.

Comment: Does that mean its additive (210/260% with crit/IE) or multiplicative (220/275%) ?

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk There is no additive crit. If it were 100*2 + 10, that would mean the extra damage wouldn't crit at all. If the extra damage does crit, it's (100+10)*2, or 100*2 + 10*2, which is the same.

Comment: The way I meant it was that the attack would crit for 100 then add the 10 from fishbones. But the (100+10)*2 makes more sense than that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you should be using the minigun, switch to the rockets to clear large minion clumps while pushing, or if you want to deal aoe harass to champions that are next to minions you are last hitting.

Answer (score 0):

utilise 'pow pow' in early game farming situations and always in a 1v1 fight or when you are kiting someone.'fish bones' is more used as a wave clear method or when using it to get the kill on an enemy with one last auto attack if they are generally far away.You could also take advantage of fishbones in a teamfight if you are closely protected by your team in dealing massive damage if your opponents are all klumped up in a group.

However most of the time you will dedicate most your damage in pow pow

Answer (score 0):

I generally find Fishbones useful for the range. The mana cost is pretty painful early on, in-lane, and I prefer to save mana for W spamming. I tend to use Fishbones more in teamfights where keeping your distance is useful, or chasing for kills. When dueling an opponent, where lifesteal is critical, building up three ASPD stacks on Pow-Pow is usually more useful than the 110% damage on Fishbones, in that you can heal more with the faster attack speed.